# AJAX Solr returning the default wildcard *:* and not what I query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, solr

I am currently integrating JavaScript framework AJAX Solr to my domain. I am trying to query words such as 'doctorate' or 'programs' but the console is reporting '*:*' only the default wildcard.

The reuters example (/ajax-solr/examples/reuters/index.html) makes two ajax requests per Chrome console:

```
                Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://evolvingweb.ca/solr/reuters/select?facet=true&q=*%3A*&facet.field=to…&wt=json&json.wrf=jQuery17206055877613835037_1383157992399&_=1383157992504". 

                Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://evolvingweb.ca/solr/reuters/select?rows=0&facet=true&facet.limit=-1&…&wt=json&json.wrf=jQuery17206055877613835037_1383157992400&_=1383157992844".
```

Whereas I am only seeing this:

```
                Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:8983/solr/rockies/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&json.wrf=jQuery17107057890424039215_1383158110410&_=1383158110688".
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
                <form action="/search.htm" id="search-form">
                      <ul id="search">
                        <input type="text" id="query" name="query" autocomplete="off">
                      </ul>    
                </form>
```

Under this construct, the query would report onto the search results page (search.htm).

Additionally, I am using only the pager and result widget and have commented out widgets like TagcloudWidget, CurrentSearchWidget, AutocompleteWidget, CountryCodeWidget and CalendarWidget.

Here is what I have included globally (assuming jQuery 1.7.1 is the dependency):

```
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/search.css">
                <script src="js/search.js"></script>
                <script src="js/Core.js"></script>
                <script src="js/AbstractManager.js"></script>
                <script src="js/Manager.jquery.js"></script>
                <script src="js/Parameter.js"></script>
                <script src="js/ParameterStore.js"></script>
                <script src="js/AbstractWidget.js"></script>
                <script src="js/ResultWidget.js"></script>
                <script src="js/PagerWidget.js"></script>
```

All JS files are consolidated into one 'js' folder. Pastebins available upon request.

I've confirmed through SOLR's UI (i.e. http://localhost:8983/solr/#/rockies/query) that the JSON can return different results aside from the wildcard (ie 'doctorate' or 'programs').

My environment and app versions are as follows:

- AJAX Solr
- Nutch 1.7
- Solr 4.5
- MAC OSX (10.8.5)
- java version "1.6.0_51"

The solr.log file currently reports [this](http://pastebin.com/zSpERJZA).

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This should be resolved. See [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GyC4RMva)

Comment: Just for anyone who comes along later, the "Resource interpreted as Script" part is not necessarily a bad thing and is separate from the query error.

Answer (score 0):

The reuters example from the Ajax-solr project will base all queries on the [**Facet**](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters) component. The key name for the solr facet component parameter is 'fq' so if you are applying a facet search over a field named 'category' you will find something like this http://YourSolrServer.com/select?param1&param2&paramN&**fq=category:mySearchString**&q=* : *

So really what is happening in Reuters Solr example is that they are applying filters over the facet component with the parameter 'fq' without no modifying the 'q' parameter at all, just saying.. q=* : *  give me all.. because I will filter by 'fq' .

If you need to apply search over fields **without** using facet you have to code your custom modification adding an js or jquery function to read what you have in your search input.

You can try this

Html

```
<input type="text" id="query" name="query" autocomplete="off">
<input type="button" onclick="searchThis();" value="Search Now">
```

Js

```
function searchThis(){
  var queryValue = $('#query').val();
  Manager.store.addByValue('q', queryValue);
  Manager.doRequest();
}
```

PS: I haven't try the code.. but yours should be very close to this..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both our methods are close. What I did however was bake the variable (in your case queryValue) into my version of the reuters.js file aka search.js. The only difference is that I'm pulling the value from the window.location object versus the value of the input field. My changes are on pastebin and indeed work, http://pastebin.com/GyC4RMva

No inline JavaScript needed on the input tag.